# .net - C# - read database without doing postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm new with .cshtml. I have some experience with .aspx and have the following problem.

I have users in a database that have a ranking. I want to show in a page a link to the highest rated user.

In aspx, I would have a postback to the codebehind and there get the user with highest ranking.

I have heard that in cshtml you can calculate this before loading the page, and it is more efficient. Also, why is some code inside { } ?

I thought it was C# code, but visual studio underlines it red like it is an error.

Comment: Questions on SO need to come with some code, especially when you`re talking about some code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just starting with Razor I’d recommend you to read http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-(c)

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but a good way to do something like this is using an extension method. You can add a class HtmlHelperExtensions.cs that contains:

```
public static IHtmlString GetHighestRatedUrl(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    int id = SomehowGetYourIdFromDatabase();
    string url = "http://www.yourpage.com/User/" + id;
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(url);
}
```

When using Razor syntax (cshtml), what you put inside @{ // This is code } is C# code that gets executed before loading the page. You probably have an intelisense problem with VS, that's why it's not recognizing the code.

So when you write:

```
<a href="@GetHighestRatedUrl()"> click to see highest rated user </a>
```

the extension method code will be executed and you will obtain the ID before loading the page (you can add any logic you need here).

Keep in mind that if this code takes too long to execute, the page will take a lot of time to load (try and keep it simple).